# Initialized Error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

so i'm trying to create a for loop for my array list but i keep getting an initialized error regarding my variable "F" in the for loop

. When i use an enhanced for loop, my code runs fine but i want to practice using the regular for loop.

i have declared my variable wrigleys to determine the size of the array but i feel like this could be my issue.

Thanks for the help

```
     import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collections;



   public class Assignment1abdallahelgohary {  
   public static void main (String args[]) { 



  //create array
  ArrayList<Integer> bob = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 //insert/add elements 
  bob.add(2);
  bob.add(1);
  bob.add(4);
  bob.add(3);


  int wrigleys = bob.size();
 //System.out.println(wrigleys);


 //organize list
 Collections.sort(bob);



 //print out 
 for (int f; f < wrigleys; f ++) {
  //   for (int fruit: bob){
 System.out.println(f);
 }



  }
  }
```

Comment: Try `int f = 0`. Also try `println(bob.get(f))`.

Comment: f is not initialised

Comment: @Andreas so when using the regular for loop i have to initialize the variable not like in the enhanced for loop?

Comment: `for (int f = 0; f < wrigleys; f ++)`. Please read the Java guide on `for` loops, e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials - The for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). This is not a teaching site. Do you own research. *Any* example `for` loop would have shown you this!!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Assignment1abdallahelgohary 
{  
    public static void main (String args[]) 
    { 
              int f=0;
              //create array
              ArrayList<Integer> bob = new ArrayList<Integer>();

             //insert/add elements 
              bob.add(2);
              bob.add(1);
              bob.add(4);
              bob.add(3);


              int wrigleys = bob.size();
             //System.out.println(wrigleys);


             //organize list
             Collections.sort(bob);



             //print out 
             for (f=0; f < wrigleys; f ++) {
              //   for (int fruit: bob){
             System.out.println(f);
             }
  }
}
```